# How to pass JSF variable to jQuery

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Suppose i have JSF page

```
 <h:body>       
    <h:form id="formID" prependId="false">      

        <h:outputText id="randomID" value="#{randomNumber.random}"/>      
        <h:commandButton id="buttonID" 
                         value="Random"
                         onclick="myArrayList(countries)" />   //just example  
    </h:form>
</h:body>

@ViewScoped
public class RandomNumber {

    private int totalCountries;
    private String data = "Afghanistan, Albania, Zimbabwe";
    private List<String> countries;

    public RandomNumber() {

        countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ",");

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            countries.add(st.nextToken().trim());
        }
        totalCountries = countries.size();

    } //end of constructor

} //end of class RandomNumber
```

.js file

```
function myArrayList(countries) {

    .....

}
```

See when user click on button then i want to call Jquery function whom i am passing my ArrayList. Is it possible to pass your current JSF variable with  values  to javascript or jQuery?

Thanks

**EDIT**
*****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***-*

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formID" prependId="false">

        <h:outputText id="countries" value="#{countries.countries}" style="display:none"/>
        <h:inputHidden id="hiddenCountries" value="#{countries.countries}" />

        <h:commandButton id="buttonID"
                         value="Random"
                         onclick="myArrayList()"/>

    </h:form>

</h:body>

@ViewScoped
public class Countries {

    private int totalCountries;
    private String data = "Afghanistan, Albania, Zimbabwe";
    private List<String> countries;

    /** Creates a new instance of Countries */
    public Countries() {

        countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ",");

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            countries.add(st.nextToken().trim());
        }
        totalCountries = countries.size();

    } //end of constructor

    public List<String> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(List<String> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

} //end of class Countries

function myArrayList() {

    alert(jQuery('#countries').html());
    alert(jQuery('#hiddenCountries').val()) //when using h:inputHidden

} //end of function myArrayList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
<h:inputHidden id="someID" value="#{randomNumber.data}/>
```

(dont forget to added getter/setter to your data in the bean )

change your onclick of the `h:commandButton`

```
onclick="myArrayList()" // or onclick="myArrayList(#{SomeELExpressioGoesHere})"
```

change your js function into

```
function myArrayList(inputParam) {
    alert(jQuery('#someID').val());
    var yourJSString = jQuery('#someID').val();
    var myArray = yourJSString.split(','); //when string is Afghanistan,Albania,Zimbabwe (no spaces)
    alert(myArray[inputParam]);
}
```

in order to transfer your js string into array just use

```
var yourJSString = jQuery('#someID').val()
var myArray = yourJSString.split(','); //when string is Afghanistan,Albania,Zimbabwe (no spaces)
```

you might be needed to change `someID` into other id selector if you wont set prependId=false in your form... or simply use a broaded jquery selector like

```
 alert(('input[id$="someID"]').val());
```

**EDIT**

Look at my example , you should work with your String data variable and not the countries , cause you should pass the data as string only and not as array... after you will pass the data variable to js you can manipulate it with simple slpit js function to make it back an array in your js... you are getting Conversion Error setting value '[Afghanistan, Albania, Zimbabwe]' for 'null cause you are trying to set String into array... probably the getter of countries converted implicitly the java array into string and when you try to submit it back (string into array) you getting the exception

in order to set from js back to to bean :

```
jQuery('#someID').val("Some new String goes here");
```

then when you will submit the form.. the value will be set back to server

Comment: but this will give you the value of the outputText.Not the ArrayList(countries)? I think i can't do it in this way because my ArrayList is a server side code and jquery is a client side. How can i pass my server code to jquery by just calling function.... I don't know am i right or not?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks :) Yes you are right i am getting all the values that are in the ArrayList. I edit my question. But i am also getting error after i click on the alert box. **Conversion Error setting value '[Afghanistan, Albania, Zimbabwe]' for 'null Converter'. **. Why i an getting this? Also one more question. Out of scope but related to it... OK i passed my Java variable value to jQuery. What if i want my ArrayList become null in the JQuery. Like i want that i use something like this in the jQuery. `countries = null` and that thing reflect in my Java code. Is it possible ?

Comment: HHmm now i understood. Actually when i am using `List<String> getCountries()` then i am getting String Array. I can manipulate the Array values by using JS split function. And i am getting null error because `<h:outputText />` needs only one value not Array. OK:) One thing more if it will not bother you. You mention that i can use syntax `onclick="myArrayList(#{SomeELExpressioGoesHere})"
`. Means first my JSF function invoke and the result of that function as a String or Array i can pass to myArrayList() function. But if your button inside the form then it will submit the form. ...continue

Comment: You can prevent the button default action by using `event.preventDefault()`. can i pass event object to my function like `myArrayList(value, event){..}`. `onclick="myArrayList(#{SomeELExpressioGoesHere}, event)"` . Is it right? Actually i want that when user click on the button, then on onclick my JSF function get call, that return value, and on the basis of that value i decide whether form should be submit or not. Can i do it? Thanks

Comment: better solution is to use return false; inside the myArrayList(); based on some logic just do return false; when you do not want to submit the form , or return true; when you want to submit... (absolutely no need to use event.preventDefault())

Comment: HHmm thanks :) Sorry to bother you once again.  One more question please. Suppose if i use action also in my button like `<h:commandButton action = ... onclick=...`. Then i think first onclick method will call, then the action method will call. Am i right? If this is the behavior, then can i swap this action? Means first action method get call, then onclick.  Is it possible?

Comment: no, first the onclick than the action , BUT if your onclick will return false, the action wont be called... b.t.w next time you better split your questions... so it will be more easy to find them for someone else... later on... in case other will bump into similar issues...

Comment: HHmm thanks Daniel:) Actually i wanted to know that how can we pass variable from JSF to jQuery and jQuery to JSF. But for setting value from jQuery to JSF the form should be submit. Is it? Without submitting the form you can't set your Java variable? This is my last question of this post......Sorry :)

Comment: you can use f:ajax to execute a more specific component to the server... Or you can submit the form , either way you do need to send the data back to server (submit or f:ajax execute)